# powershell get current date format being used by system

Tags: powershell

How can I use powershell to get the current system date format for example if I was reading a log file using powershell I would like to know if 2012-03-01 is in yyyy-mm-dd or yyyy-dd-mm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you the DateTime formats for the machine's current culture:

```
[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat
```

Comment: Or better yet, `([cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat).LongDatePattern`

Comment: If you get an error using the [CultureInfo] type accelerator, spell it out: [System.Globalization.CultureInfo].